# If $A+B=(4n+1)\frac{\pi}{3}$, where $n \in \mathbb Z$, then what is the value of $(1+\tan A)(1+\tan B)?$

Tags: trigonometry

If $A+B=(4n+1)\frac{\pi}{3}$, where $n \in \mathbb Z$, then what is the value of $(1+\tan A)(1+\tan B)?$

**My attempt**

$A+B=(4n+1)\frac{\pi}{3}\implies B=(4n+1)\frac{\pi}{3}-A$

Applying the value of $B$ in $(1+\tan A)(1+\tan B).$

We get

$$(1+\tan A)(1+\tan B)=(1+\tan A)(1+\tan ((4n+1)\frac{\pi}{3}-A).$$
$$=(1+\tan A)(1+\frac{\tan ((4n+1)\frac{\pi}{3})-\tan (A)}{1+\tan ((4n+1)\frac{\pi}{3} \cdot \tan (A)})$$
$$=(1+\tan A)(\frac{1+\tan ((4n+1)\frac{\pi}{3} \cdot \tan (A)+\tan ((4n+1)\frac{\pi}{3})-\tan (A)}{1+\tan ((4n+1)\frac{\pi}{3} \cdot \tan (A)})$$
How do I reduce further?should I find values for each $n$? I know for each values of $n$ answer is different.

Based on Quippy's comment
$A+B=(4n+1)\frac{\pi}{3}\implies \tan(A+B)=\tan((4n+1)\frac{\pi}{3})$
$$\implies \tan(A+B)=\tan((4n+1)\frac{\pi}{3})$$
$$\implies \frac{\tan(A)+\tan(B)}{1-\tan(A)\cdot\tan(B)}=\tan((4n+1)\frac{\pi}{3})$$
$$\implies \tan(A)+\tan(B)=(\tan((4n+1)\frac{\pi}{3}))(1-\tan(A)\cdot\tan(B))$$

$$(1+\tan{A})(1+\tan{B})=1+\tan{A}+\tan{B}+\tan{A}\tan{B}$$
$$=1+(\tan((4n+1)\frac{\pi}{3}))(1-\tan(A)\cdot\tan(B))+\tan{A}\tan{B}$$

Still I am not getting the answer.

Comment: For questions like this you don't want to find the actual values of $A$ and $B$, try tanning both sides of your original equation

Comment: I don't understand. May I get more explanation?

Comment: You see how if you expand $(1+\tan{A})(1-\tan{B})$ you get $1+\tan{A}+\tan{B}+\tan{A}\tan{B}?$ You also see how that looks pretty close to the expansion of $\tan{A+B}$? I'm not certain because I haven't attempted the qn but I think the idea is to manipulate that to match what they want you to find

Comment: Let me check your idea.

Comment: @Quippy still I am not getting the answer.

Comment: Can you compute
$$\tan((4n+1)\frac{\pi}{3})?$$

Comment: yes. when $n=0, \tan((4n+1)\frac{\pi}{3})=\sqrt{3}$,$n=1, \tan((4n+1)\frac{\pi}{3})=-\sqrt{3}$ and $n=2, \tan((4n+1)\frac{\pi}{3})=0$. I am getting three different values.

Comment: See if you can find the value of $A-B$ because I tried simplifying and $(1+\tan{A})(1+\tan{B})=2\frac{\sin{(A+B)}+\cos{(A-B)}}{\cos{(A-B)}+\cos{(A+B)}}$

Comment: $A-B=A-B=A-(4n+1)\frac{\pi}{3}+A=2A-(4n+1)\frac{\pi}{3}$

Comment: I am getting an answer involving $A$.

Comment: Which will be equivalent to my expression.

Comment: Uh, by rearranging your first statement and matching it with the general solutions formulae I got $\tan{\frac34(A+B)}=1$ and $\cos{\frac32(A+B)}=0$, I dunno if that helps

Comment: How do you arrive at this $\tan{\frac34(A+B)}=1$?

Comment: If you re-arrange the given equation you get $\frac34(A+B)=\pi{n}+\frac{\pi}{4}$ which is the form of the tan general solutions, so you know $\tan{\frac34(A+B)}=\tan^{-1}{\frac{\pi}{4}}$

Comment: From this I could prove $(1+\tan(3/4.A)).((1+\tan(3/4.B))=2.$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130217/discussion-between-mathematician-reloaded-and-quippy).